# Add component to track label on React Material UI Slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using the react material-ui slider as a timeline for selecting different data sources to my app.
I use it to select data from whichever year there might be data.
My marks vector is an object with a value representing the year and the label representing the concatenated sources' names for that year.
My problem is, the number of sources can get arbitrarily long, hence some overlapping of these names are already showing on the track label, as shown in the picture below:
[image]

What I would like is, instead of showing the names as is, I would show an information icon which upon hover of the mouse, the names would appear in a tooltip...
Is this possible?
I've tried the ariaLabel function, but with no avail.

Thanks in advance

The source code for the slider is below:

```
function DiscreteSlider() {
const min = getMinValue();
const max = getMaxValue();

return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>     
    <Slider
      color='primary'
      track={false}
      min={min-1}
      max={max+1}
      step={null}
      valueLabelDisplay="on"
      marks={marks}
      defaultValue={min-1}
      value={valor}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </div>
);
```

}